# Express the DUAL norm in terms of a Matrix

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, numerical-methods

Given a symmetric positive definite matrix $M$, define the norm $\|x\|_M = \sqrt{\|Mx\|^2} $.Express the dual norm in terms of $M$.

I know, to solve this problem need to consider the Langrangian. 
i.e : $L(x) = y.x + \frac{\lambda\|Mx\|^2}{2}$

But I don't know How to proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming the space you work on is $\mathbb{R}^n$. Given a symmetric, positive definite matrix $M$, you have a complete space equipped with an inner product, a Hilbertspace.
I will denote the inner product with 
$$
\langle x,y \rangle_M=\langle Mx,My \rangle
$$
where $\langle \cdot ,\cdot \rangle$ denotes the euclidean standard inner product.
Then, by the Riesz representation theorem, every functional/element in the dual space $D=(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$ is given by:
$$
\phi(x)=\langle x,y \rangle_M
$$
for some $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Using the defintion of the dual space, you get to: 
$$
||\phi||_{D}=\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \frac{|\phi(x)|}{||x||_M}=\frac{\langle Mx,My \rangle}{\sqrt{\langle Mx,Mx \rangle}}
$$
At this point, it becomes hard to simplify. You could proabably get to another form by using the spectral decomposition of $M$, but it doesnt get much prettier.

Comment: However, the inner product that is compatible with the norm is the last term in your last formula. Only with $⟨x,y⟩_M=⟨Mx,My⟩$ you get indeed $\|x\|_M=\|Mx\|=\sqrt{⟨x,x⟩_M}$.

Comment: I fixed a couple of errors I made while writing the answer. It should be way better now.

Answer (score 1):

You are given $\|x\|_M=\|Mx\|$ where $M$ is invertible. By the definition of the dual norm as the operator norm on the space of linear functionals, you get using $I=M^{-1}M$
$$
\|\alpha\|_{M,\rm dual}=\sup_{x\ne 0}\frac{|α(x)|}{\|x\|_M}
=\sup_{x\ne 0}\frac{|α(M^{-1}(Mx))|}{\|Mx\|}
=\sup_{y\ne 0}\frac{|α(M^{-1}y)|}{\|y\|}
=\|(M^{-1})^*α\|_{\rm dual}
$$
where the pull-back notation $F^*α=α\circ F$ was used.

---

Minimizing the quoted Lagrangian uses the same trick, assuming that the original norm is Euclidean
$$
L(x,y)=y^Tx+\fracλ2\|Mx\|^2=\fracλ2\|(λM)^{-1}y+Mx\|^2-\frac1{2λ}\|M^{-1}y\|^2
$$
where you get the minimum if the first term is zero, which is always possible for some $x$.